# How to get the user that modified an object? django-simple-history

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I am trying to save the history of an object by using django-simply-history library,
so far i can see the changes of the object itself but not the user that made the changes.

I have the following set up.

Settings:

```py
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'simple_history',
    # ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

from apps.companies.models import Company
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    dateUpdated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Then in the Shell i do:

```ipython
customer = Customer.objects.all().last()

customer.name = "Test"

customer.save()

customer.history.all().last()

Out[79]: <HistoricalCustomer: Customer object (d2211cc1-9762-4f6d-9086-634deee95b1e) as of 2021-08-24 09:28:44.978543+00:00>

# How can I print the user that changed the object????
customer.history.all().last()_history_user
```

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple history middleware will store the user that made the change in the `.history_user` field of the history record. You thus can obtain the latest user that changed the `Customer` object with:

```
customer.history.all().last().history_user
```

Beware that you can only make changes with a user in the webserver, for example with a view, or with the `ModelAdmin`. If you make changes with the Django shell itself, there is no "*active* user", and in that case the user stored in the historical record will be `NULL`/`None`.

Comment: customer.history.all().last().history_user In the shell won't print anything
but still it does not give any error, I don't know why exactly.

Comment: @Jorge: because if you alter objects in the shell, then there is *no* user, so the user is unknown, and `history_user` is set to `None` in that case.

Comment: @Jorge: you thus should make a change through the website, and then in the shell (or the webserver) you can inspect the user that made the latest change.

Comment: @Jorge: Django's shell is not attached to a Django user, so hence the middleware of simple history can not capture any user, not because they did not implement it, but because it makes no sense conceptually.

Comment: Ohhh alright, thank you very much !!!!!! then everything it is fine.